# Switched ISP, but Windows 10 DHCP still remembers my old ISP's DNS servers

Tags: windows-10, dns, home-networking

I tried these commands, with a reboot afterwards but still Windows remembers the old DNS servers:

`ipconfig /flushdns`

`ipconfig /release Ethernet*` followed by `ipconfig /renew`

Will the problem fix itself when the lease renews?

Comment: Should do.  The flush takes some time.

Comment: When you switched ISP, did you also switch modem/router? Have you ever set manually the DNS servers in Windows?

Comment: @harry yes, ATT gave me a new router (BGW320-500), since I went from a cable provider (where I used a Motorola MB8600).

Comment: @John the old DNS servers are still listed in `ipconfig /all`.

Comment: Try the following (all steps) :    Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer
...  See if the Reset helps.

Comment: @John will try that.